mysql engine is failing to start
I am trying to restart mysql however I am getting stuck in this loop. Attached below is the dump from MySQL error log.
I have tried doing innodb_force_recovery = 4 to back up the tables, but even that fails. Please suggest how to get this up and running.
2024-09-21T11:41:21.146039Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 287290
2024-09-21T11:41:21.155269Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013907] [InnoDB] Deprecated configuration parameters innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group have been used to compute innodb_redo_log_capacity=1073741824. Please use innodb_redo_log_capacity instead.
2024-09-21T11:41:21.156630Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-09-21T11:41:23.407433Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: fut0lst.ic:82:addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >= FIL_PAGE_DATA thread 140535711876864
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2024-09-21T11:41:23Z UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
BuildID[sha1]=26eb959d4d27330a3b28319eb9ea144b2a96f707
Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x100000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x41) [0x5609f1d2c771]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(print_fatal_signal(int)+0x39b) [0x5609f0b9ed6b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_server_abort()+0x76) [0x5609f0b9eeb6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_abort()+0xe) [0x5609f1d2670e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ut_dbg_assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, unsigned long)+0x349) [0x5609f1fca2e9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x258619c) [0x5609f1fa419c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(trx_rseg_init_thread(void*, unsigned long)+0x663) [0x5609f1fab383]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<Detached_thread, void (*)(void*, unsigned long), void*, unsigned long> > >::_M_run()+0xcc) [0x5609f1f9ff4c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xd6df4) [0x7fd6dc93cdf4]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8609) [0x7fd6dca58609]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x43) [0x7fd6dc629353]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.

Update 1: I have been able to start the server with innodb_force_recovery = 6. The size of the db is around 300GB. What is the best way to fix the issue. Is there any way to understand which table is the culprit and then fix it?

Since you've successfully started MySQL with innodb_force_recovery = 6, your priority is to identify the corrupted table(s) and recover the data. Here's a step-by-step approach:

Backup Data Immediately
Since recovery mode 6 is the highest level and very risky (read-only mode), back up all your databases immediately using a tool like mysqldump:
bash
Copy code
mysqldump --all-databases --skip-lock-tables > backup.sql
This will ensure you have a backup of all data before further troubleshooting.

Identify Corrupted Tables
Check the MySQL error log for any clues on specific tables causing issues.
Alternatively, run CHECK TABLE on each InnoDB table to identify corruption:
sql
Copy code
CHECK TABLE table_name EXTENDED;
Focus on tables with large data or that were in heavy use before the crash.

Repair Corrupted Tables
If you identify the corrupted table(s), use these approaches:


For non-critical tables, you can drop and recreate the table.
For important tables, attempt to export the data and re-import:
bash
Copy code
mysqldump database_name table_name > table_backup.sql
If the dump fails, you can try using tools like innodb-tools for deeper recovery or attempt to repair individual tables by running:
sql
Copy code
REPAIR TABLE table_name;
4. Lower Recovery Mode and Restart
After you've backed up the data, try lowering the innodb_force_recovery value gradually (e.g., to 4 or 2) and restart MySQL. Ideally, the database should start without requiring any recovery mode.

Rebuild Database if Necessary
If the corruption persists, consider creating a fresh database instance, restoring from the backup (backup.sql), and importing data into the new instance.

This process should help stabilize the server. Let me know if you need help with any specific part of the recovery!

Hi, thanks for your response. I have identified te corrupt table. However I am unable to drop it since the engine is running with innodb_force_recovery = 6. What are the other ways in which this table can be fixed or dropped?

Since you're running with innodb_force_recovery = 6, the InnoDB engine is in read-only mode, preventing you from dropping the corrupted table directly. Here's how you can proceed:

Lower innodb_force_recovery to 4 or 3
First, try lowering the recovery mode to a lower value, which still allows you to perform some operations like dropping the table:

Edit your MySQL configuration (my.cnf or my.ini):
bash
Copy code
innodb_force_recovery = 4
Restart MySQL, and then try to drop the table:
sql
Copy code
DROP TABLE database_name.corrupt_table_name;
If innodb_force_recovery = 4 doesn’t work, try lowering it to innodb_force_recovery = 3 or 2.

Drop Table Using innodb_force_recovery = 1 or Without Recovery Mode
If you can start MySQL with innodb_force_recovery = 1, the database will allow more write operations. You can attempt to drop the table at this level, although some tables may still be read-only. If successful, you can drop the table normally.

Use ALTER TABLE to Rename or Move the Table
If dropping the table is not possible, try renaming it first:


sql
Copy code
ALTER TABLE corrupt_table_name RENAME TO corrupt_table_backup;
This will isolate the table for later analysis or deletion.

Manually Remove the Table from Disk
As a last resort, you can manually remove the table from the filesystem, but be cautious as this can lead to further issues:

Locate the table’s .frm, .ibd, and other files on disk (typically in /var/lib/mysql/database_name/).
Delete these files corresponding to the corrupted table.
Restart MySQL and then run DROP TABLE to remove the metadata.
5. Rebuild the Corrupted Table
If you need to preserve the table, you can try exporting the data:
Use SELECT * INTO OUTFILE to dump the data from the corrupted table (if readable).
Drop the table after lowering innodb_force_recovery, then recreate it and re-import the data.
Let me know if you want more details on any of these steps!

Hi, the lowest i can go to is till 5. Below that the MySQL server fails to start.

Lucas, will be wise to merge your answers.

I tried removing the table.ibd file, the '#innodb_temp'
and the '#innodb_redo' folder and starting the server in mode 6. However, I was unable to start the server.  I couldn't find any .frm file. What are the other files that need to be removed?
